# variable scope when dealing with event handlers

Tags: event-handling, scope, lua, coronasdk

```
function World:draw()
    --draw the tiles based on 2d int array
    --draw the player
    --draw the monsters
    --show what you need to based on camera
    self.map[0][0]=display.newImage("dirt_tile.png",i,j)
end
```

I can't access any of my world object's properties in there when I use the event handler:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame",World.draw)
```

Is there a different kind of eventListener I can use, or is there a different way to instantiate the eventListener so the self-referencing context stays intact?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
World = { count=0 }

function World:enterFrame()
    self.count = self.count + 1
    print("count = " .. self.count)
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", World)
```

See [this API reference page](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/objectaddeventlistener) for details.

Comment: I have an object called "World" that i defined with a "function World:new()" constructor.  i have a table in that function called "local self={}" and i fill it with my "map" (or 2d int array).  I can't access it even modifying my code to fit yours.  In your answer, you were accessing an array named "World" and a property in that array named "count," while I'm trying to access the properties of the object i created.

Comment: Tables and objects are exactly the same thing in Lua. You may have other issues going on, but without source code, I can't really tell.

Comment: I'll be happy to look at it further if you want to post minimal working source code that duplicates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In you named your table `local self = {}`, then it may collide with the implicit `self` parameter.

The `function World:draw()` is just a Lua syntax sugar for `World.draw = function(self)`. By working with `self`, you are using whatever first parameter the runtime event handler is passing to your function (judging from the API, it passes `event`, which you will get as `self`).

Try naming the table you want to access differently (like `local this`) and see if it works.

Comment: the way I read it he only did `local self={}` in his :new() function.